# How can I re-stain a table without streaking?

Tags: wood, staining

I purchased a new telephone table/bench that has a slick red mahogany-color (I do not know what type wood this actually is) table top, which unfortunately my cat immediately scratched before I could put a protective cover over it.

I sanded it all the way down to bare wood, ending with 220 grit and going with the grain, and endeavored to stain it with an oil-based semi-transparent stain, but the stain would not absorb, making little circles and ringlets.

I have encountered this before and thought there might be something that had penetrated the wood, so I again sanded, ending with 220 grit and, of course, going with the grain.  This time I tried a solid stain that matched the rest of the table/bench, but it was streaked-looking (not to the touch but to the eye).

I tried rag staining, and this seems to work fairly well but it was extremely dull and flat, so I tried various finishes over the top of the stain.

Everything I put on this is streaked-looking, no matter what type of brush I use.  I tried using Varathane over this in an area, but it left brush marks no matter what brush I used.  I tried using Shellac; again brush marks.  I tried using lacquer; brush marks, no matter the brush used!  When I say brush marks, I mean that you can see the marks but not feel them.

It will not even out and looks smooth.  Everything looks streaked.  I have stained and painted a lot for many years; I have done more work with semi-transparent stain than anything else, but this is the first time I have not been able to come up with a solution.

I had a similar problem with the pocking and circling of stain when someone had used Pledge on a piece of furniture, and I finally, through trial and error, worked that out, but it was an endeavor.  Since I do not know the manner in which this piece of furniture was finished out, I am just guessing what to do.

What could cause brush marks to be seen (not felt) no matter what brush is used or how careful the application?  I am so frustrated.  I need to find something that is close to Red Mahogany and has a shine to it that will stay on the wood and not cause little circles, but the only thing that did not circle was the flat solid stain and when I try to add some gloss to it (Varathane, shellac, lacquer, etc.), it shows brush marks no matter what brush I use.

Any suggestions?  I really would appreciate some advice, as I am at my wit's end.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be hard for us to help, but perhaps some pictures would make your problem clearer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: If the furniture is from a famous maker, it would also be helpful to know which one.

Comment: Pics would definitely help, and check out the finishing related tags at [woodworking.se].

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why the VtC - there's no request for shopping tips or product recommendations, the question asks (eventually) "What could cause brush marks...?" way down in the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: I normally use a rag for stain. Wipe on, wipe off. No brush marks. You might get better help at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com.